# Azure Synapse pyspark translates STRING datatype into varchar(8000) for external table

Tags: sql-server, azure, pyspark, azure-synapse

I try to load an external table in Azure Synpase using a PySpark notebook but the datatypes seem to mismatch. When I initialize the table I execute (stripped down example):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE LANDING_DB.Opportunity (
 AccountId varchar(255),
 Id varchar(255),
 Name STRING,
 Description STRING
)
USING DELTA LOCATION 'abfss://XXX@XXX.dfs.core.windows.net/Landing/ABC/Opportunity/'
```

via

```
spark.sql()
```

Yet the external table uses 'varchar(8000)' as datatype for the Name and Description column. I would like to use varchar(max) as especially the Description column can have a lot of text.

Am I missing some settings or is this a bug?

The database is the serverless pool on the synapse instance.

Help would be appreciated, thank you in advance

Best, Sven

Comment: Can you share the error?

Comment: Hi, there is not really an error. I define the columns in the spark notebook with datatype STRING, yet the table that is created has datatype varchar(8000). Up to this point there is no error. Only if I query the table after I have loaded some data I get the error, that data would be truncated. This, of course, comes from the fact that the data is sometimes larger than 8000 chars. So my issue is that I expected pyspark to generate column with varchar(max) if the datatype is STRING, yet it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all note the tip: Try to make VARCHAR() as short as possible. Avoid VARCHAR(MAX) if possible because it can impair performance.

It seems that it makes STRING automatically to varchar(8000) because it infers the length. See https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/synapse-analytics/sql/best-practices-serverless-sql-pool.md#check-inferred-data-types

Instead of using STRING you can use varchar(x) and then put a higher number. Maybe you know what the maximum could be in the Description? varchar() takes an integer as the argument, and the max value of an integer is 2,147,483,647. I don't think your description can get that long? So better put a lower number which will also not be reached.

Comment: Thank you! I tried that and it did work. We just set it to 100.000 and it converts just fine to varchar(max). We will check over the next few weeks how long the column will actually be and then perhapt adjust the pipeline/script accordingly.